# openssl s_client with multiple commands

Tags: linux, openssl

I'm trying to list my imap email folders with openssl s_client:

> openssl s_client -quiet -crlf -connect imap.server

It works fine, and I can type in

> a capability
>
> b logout

Both commands are executed perfectly.
But when I put both commands in a file (I'm on ubuntu16), say "aa.txt" and I pipe this file into openssl, openssl just executes the first command (capability) and hangs, never executing the second one:

> cat aa.txt | openssl s_client -quiet -crlf -connect imap.server

Why and how can I execute multiple commands in a file by the imap server through connectssl ?

Thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pipeline openssl commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47900642/pipeline-openssl-commands)